# How do I make Import-Clixml read a custom credentials XML file?

Tags: xml, powershell, credentials

I'm obtaining credentials for a Xen pool master server using `Get-Credentials`. I'm saving the credentials to an `XML` file using `Export-Clixml`. I want to add an element to the `XML` file created by `Export-Clixml` to store the Xen pool name and the Xen pool master URL to the `XML` file.

Problem: I create the credentials `XML` file using Export-Clixml and then modify the `XML` file to add the extra element. However, when I read the `XML` file using `Import-Clixml`, it throws an error: `Import-Clixml : Obj XML tag is not recognized.`

How do I make `Import-Clixml` read my custom credentials XML file to obtain the credentials without throwing an error due to my custom object?

Comment: So what is the use-case of your Q&A? Versus creating multiple credentials files or creating a hashtable of credentials to export?  It seems to be overly complicated

Comment: I currently have a PS script that accepts the url of a Xen pool master and the creds for it. Given these, it presents a list of pool VMs so the user can pick existing VM snapshots to delete and the VMs to create new snapshots for. I'm making an unattended version to be run by the Win Scheduler. So, the unattended script needs a 1) a pre-prepared creds file, 2) a pre-prepared list of pool VMs, 3) the pool master url. So, it would be nice if the creds file has the url of the pool master (that was provided when the creds files was created and used to do a test-connect to the pool master)

Answer (score 1):

My original approach was to locate the `XML` schema for the `XML` file produced by `Export-Clixml` with the hope that the schema supports some kind of generic string element. However, I was unable to locate the schema.

The solution was to use the `-first` argument of the `Import-Clixml` cmdlet.

First, I created an `XML` file using `Export-Clixml`, and then I added a second `Obj` element (`<Obj RefId="99" xmlns="">`)

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <ToString>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</ToString>
    <Props>
      <S N="UserName">UUUUU</S>
      <SS N="Password">PPPP...PPPPP</SS>
    </Props>
  </Obj>
  <Obj RefId="99" xmlns="">
    <my-element-name my-element-attribute="AAAAA">EEEEEE</my-element-name>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

To obtain the credentials, I read the `XML` like this:

```
$creds = $Import-Clixml -first 1 -path <fq path to xml file>
```

`-first 1` forces `Import-Clixml` to read only the `<Obj RefId="0">` element (and ignore my custom element)

Then, I re-read the XML file using an `XMLReader` to obtain my custom element

**Edit 1**

Changed approach as per Jeroen Mostert's suggestion

Notes:

`$ExportXmlFile.FileName` comes from system.windows.forms.savefiledialog

`$cred` is loaded with output from get-credentials

```
$cred | Export-Clixml -Path $ExportXmlFile.FileName -Force

$xml = [xml] (type $ExportXmlFile.FileName)

[System.Xml.XmlElement]$root = $xml.DocumentElement

[System.Xml.XmlComment]$c = $xml.CreateComment(("poolName="+$textBoxXenPoolName.Text + "," + "poolMasterUrl="+$textBoxXenPoolMasterUrl.Text))
$xml.InsertBefore($c, $root);

$xml.Save($ExportXmlFile.FileName)
```

produces an xml file with a 'structured' comment that I can read and parse:

```
<!--poolName=nnnnn,poolMasterUrl=https://###.##.#.#-->
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <ToString>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</ToString>
    <Props>
      <S N="UserName">uuu</S>
      <SS N="Password">pppp...pppp</SS>
    </Props>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

Comment: If you're going to need custom code anyway, why not export an actual custom object by wrapping the result of `Get-Credentials`? Twiddling the result of `Export-Clixml` so it can't be read by a vanilla `Import` command sounds like an incredibly ugly solution. Even if, for some reason, that was the most appropriate approach, adding your stuff in a structured XML comment that you could parse and the rest of the world could ignore would probably be better. (With additional effort you can even make your object behave just as a `PSCredential` instance, but that's more advanced stuff.)

Comment: Note sure I understand what you mean by `export an actual custom object by wrapping the result of Get-Credentials`. A structured comment didn't occur to me, but I'm going to modify my code to use that approach

Comment: I mean `[PSCustomObject] @{ poolName="..."; poolMasterUrl="..."; credentials=$cred } | Export-Clixml`. PowerShell can export *any* object, including hash tables, and custom objects made of them. Given that there should really be no need to muck about with the generated XML.